# Received unknown parameters in Laravel, Cashier and Stripe

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

Before we start I'm using these versions:

`"laravel/framework": "5.4.*"`

`"laravel/cashier": "~7.0"`

I'm getting the Stripe test token back in on my Vue.js front-end fine then sending it back to the Laravel API. It's creating a customer in Stripe and saving the `stripe_id` on my User table. But I'm getting the following error:

`message: "Received unknown parameters: object, card, client_ip, created, livemode, type, used"`

I'm sending the whole token back:

```
card: {id: "card_1E6gkZ2eZvKYlo2CkU7Xebko", object: "card", address_city: null, address_country: null, address_line1: null, …}
client_ip: "5.64.000.00"
created: 1550852387
id: "tok_1E6gkZ2eZvKYlo2CyVJV9hXm"
livemode: false
object: "token"
type: "card"
used: false
```

This is the code I'm using so far to test it's working:

```
public function processSubscription(Request $request)
{
    $sub = Auth::user()
        ->newSubscription('main', 'plan_E2xs2LcXXXXXX')
        ->create($request->token);

    return $sub;
}
```

This is my front-end code, which I presume is OK as it's creating a customer:

```
methods: {
  getToken() {
    this.processing = true
    createToken().then(data => {
      console.log(data.token)
      this.processSubscription(data.token)
    })
  },
  processSubscription(token) {
    this.$axios.put('account/subscribe', {
        token: token
      }).then(response => {
          console.log(response)
          this.processing = false
        }, error => {
          console.log(error)
          this.processing = false
        }
      )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using that token in other Stripe API methods, you want to just pass its `id` (in your example code, that's `"tok_1E6gkZ2eZvKYlo2CyVJV9hXm"`) rather than the entire object.

You can see an example of passing the token as `source` when creating a customer in [the API docs](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/create).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have already tried that `this.processSubscription(data.token.id)` and get the response `"message":"No such token: tok_1E6hRG2eZvKYlo2CmpVmL3iR","status_code":500`.

Comment: Ignore that. You're right. I needed to make sure the public stripe key was the same in the front-end as the back end, which it wasn't. Working fine now :)